# core data nstableview searchbar

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, nstableview

i have a nstableview which i fill with data of core data.

**NSManagedObject**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Person)
public class Person: NSManagedObject { 
    @NSManaged public var firstName: String
    @NSManaged public var secondName: String
}
```

**RequestData**

```
 func requestData() {
        let appdelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appdelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Person")

        do {
            person = try context.fetch(request) as! [Person]
            tableViewn.reloadData()
        } catch { }
    }
```

i also have a custom cell view for my tableView.
I fill the data like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

        let view = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "Cell", owner: self) as? CustomCell

        view?.txtfirstName.stringValue = person.firstName
        view?.txtsecondName.stringValue = person.secondName
        return view
}
```

Now i would like to realize a searchbar (which i have already in my view controller) for searching with first or second name.

but i have no idea how i can realize this.

Comment: How did you implement the searchbar, what should happen when and what did you try?

Comment: If you use `NSSearchField` and `NSArrayController` then bind the predicate(s) of the search field to the filter predicate of the array controller. No coding required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set the delegate of the `NSSearchField` to the target class
- implement `controlTextDidChange`

  ```
  override func controlTextDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
      if let field = notification.object as? NSSearchField {
          let query = field.stringValue
          let predicate : NSPredicate?
          if query.isEmpty {
              predicate = nil
          } else {
              predicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName contains[cd] %@ OR lastName contains[cd] %@", query, query)
          }
          requestData(with: predicate) 
      } else {
          super.controlTextDidChange(notification)
      }
  }
  ```
- Change `requestData` to

  ```
  func requestData(with predicate : NSPredicate? = nil) {
      let appdelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
      let context = appdelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
      let request = NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName: "Person")
      request.predicate = predicate

      do {
          person = try context.fetch(request)
          tableViewn.reloadData()
      } catch { }
  }
  ```

Side note:

If you are using `NSManagedObject` subclasses create the fetch request more specific `NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName...` rather than `NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName...`, that avoids the type cast in the fetch line.